# Calculate sum of array values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sum

I'm attempting to find the total sum of the toys in the following code. My attempt is in there: calcTotal, but it only provides the result of NaN. I have used the same code in the calcTotal function before to calculate the sum of array values but for whatever reason it won't work here, any help please? The task of the program is for the user to enter dog name and toy amount, that info gets put in an object, then pushed into an array. The total amount of toys then needs to be displayed. Thank you in advance.

```
    function init() {
    var dogarray = [];
    var dogobject = {};


    var dogname = prompt("Please enter dog name");
    var toyamt = prompt("Please enter toy amount");
    while (dogname != "" && toyamt != "") {
        dogobject.name = dogname;
        dogobject.toys = toyamt;
        dogarray.push(Object.values(dogobject) + "<br />");
        dogname = prompt("Please enter dog name");
        toyamt = prompt("Please enter toys amount");

    calcTotal(dogarray);
}

}

function calcTotal(dogarray) {
    var sum=0;
    var i;

    for(i=0; i<dogarray.length; i++){
        sum = sum + dogarray[i].toys;       
    }

    document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML = "Total number of toys: " + sum;

}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: `dogarray` is an array of strings (`Object.values(dogobject) + "<br />"`), so `dogarray[i].toys` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks str, how could I adjust the code so that it works?

Comment: Remove `+ "<br />"`. Also cast `toyamt` (which is a string) to a number. For example by using `dogobject.toys = +toyamt;`

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails because your "dogarray" is filled with values of type `String` and strings don't have a "toy" property. This happens because of `Object.values(dogobject) + "<br />"`. `Object.values` returns an array of strings, which will be casted to a single string when concatenated with `"<br />"`.

Below is some working code:

```
function init() {
    var dogarray = [];
    var dogname = prompt("Please enter dog name");
    var toyamt = prompt("Please enter toy amount");
    while (dogname != "" && toyamt != "") {
        dogarray.push({ // just store raw objects
            name: dogname,
            toys: Number(toyamt) // cast to number
        });
        dogname = prompt("Please enter dog name");
        toyamt = prompt("Please enter toys amount");

        calcTotal(dogarray); // maybe move this out of the while loop?
    }
    renderAll(dogarray); // render dog names and toys
}

function renderAll(dogarray) {
    var vHtml = 'Dogs & Toys:<br />';
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < dogarray.length; i++) {
        vHtml = vHtml + dogarray[i].name + ', ' + dogarray[i].toys + '<br />';
    }

    document.getElementById('msg1').innerHTML = vHtml;
}

function calcTotal(dogarray) {
    var sum=0;
    var i;

    for(i=0; i<dogarray.length; i++){
        sum = sum + dogarray[i].toys;       
    }

    document.getElementById('msg3').innerHTML = "Total number of toys: " + sum;
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it DOES work. However, I didn't specify in my question, that part of the task is to also display the the names and amount of toys. (I didn't include this because it worked with my old code, however with your code, displaying the dogs and toys simply shows [object Object] etc. The following is the code I use to display the information: var vIndex = 0;
 var outputdog = "";
 for (vIndex = 0; vIndex < dogarray.length; vIndex++) {
 outputdog = outputdog + dogarray[vIndex];
 document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "Dogs & Toys: " + "<br />" + outputdog;

Comment: I have updated the code. All you have to do is exchange the `#output` selector on line 2 with your selector. If you want to show the info every time a new dog is added, simply move the call to `renderAll` inside the `while` loop, right below `calcTotal`

Comment: Sorry to be a pest, but is there any easier way to display the names and amount of toys? Anything similar to the code that I used (previous comment)? It's just that I'm not really using query selectors and nodes and all of that yet...

Comment: OK, I changed the code to something that's very similar to what you had initially, the only difference being the variables names and that my example starts with "Dogs & Toys:" whereas your code prepended it later.